# Compare struct field to another column Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set with ArrayType struct field and I need to filter the values of the stat field that coincide to the max_stat values. Structure of data looks like this:

```
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- stat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- max_stat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- naming: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to do something like this but it's not possible to compare Array with int. So how can I change this filter?

```
df.filter($"data.stat" === "max_stat")
.drop(max_stat)
```

Input data:

```
 data                           | max_stat | naming
[(1,0.34),(2, 0.57), (3, 0.89)] | 0.89     | example
```

Expected output:

```
 data     | naming
(3, 0.89) | example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `explode` in order to generate a line for each `element` in `data`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

ds
  .withColumn("data", explode($"data"))
  .filter($"data.stat" === $"max_stat")
  .drop($"max_stat")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+
|     data| naming|
+---------+-------+
|[3, 0.89]|example|
+---------+-------+
```

However, `explode` is a very costly operation and can be an issue if your dataset is big. Another way to do this without using explode is :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

ds
  .filter(array_contains($"data.stat", $"max_stat"))
  .withColumn("max_stat_idx", array_position($"data.stat", $"max_stat").cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("data", element_at($"data", $"max_stat_idx"))
  .drop("max_stat", "max_stat_idx")
```

Basically, it's searching for the matching value index in the `data` array, and then using this index to get the correct `element`

Comment: I get this error with explode solution for some reason `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from data#2151. data AS data#2493: need struct type but got int`

Comment: What spark version are you using ? Also, your schema is strange: `max_stat` is of type `integer`, but `max_stat` is a double in your example.

Comment: I fixed my question, max_stat is actually float. Also, I confused the namings of fields in the stack trace, it looks like this:  `Can't extract value from data#2151. id AS id#2493: need struct type but got int`

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ds.limit(1).show` please ? It's possible your data somehow don't fit the schema.